# BIM and sensor integration

Tags: visualization, heatmap, autodesk-viewer

I am working on BIM and sensor integration via Forge using
https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-iot-extensions-demo

I have already completed the following parts.

- Clone this repository
- Install dependencies: yarn install
- Setup environment variables:
- APS_CLIENT_ID - client ID of your APS application
- APS_CLIENT_SECRET - client secret of your APS application
- In public/config.js, modify APS_MODEL_URN and APS_MODEL_VIEW with your own model URN and view GUID

Now I am stuck at the next step - In ./services/iot.mocked.js
Modify the mocked up sensors, for example, changing their location (XYZ position in the model's coordinate system) or objectId (the dbID of the room the sensor should be associated with)"

I already created my sensors in Revit files with Sensor ID and sensor parameters with respect to sensor ID in my sensor Influx database. But when I upload the model into forge I can see many other different properties of sensors.

How to do BIM IoT integration via Forge.

Answer (score 0):

The [aps-iot-extensions-demo](https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-iot-extensions-demo) app makes no assumptions about what software the model is coming from, and so it simply hardcodes a list of fake sensors (incl. their location within the model) on the server side: https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-iot-extensions-demo/blob/master/services/iot.mocked.js#L1-L46.

As a first step, try identifying the coordinates of some of the sensors in your Revit model, and update the XYZ values in the *iot.mocked.js* file accordingly.

As a next step, try experimenting with the [DataView](https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-iot-extensions-demo/blob/master/public/dataview.js) class that controls where the sensors, channels, and actual sensor data is loaded from. For example, the [getSensors](https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-iot-extensions-demo/blob/master/public/dataview.js#L99-L109) method currently loads the (fake) sensors from the server but in your case you could retrieve the list of sensors by traversing the BIM model using Viewer APIs.